# what's the meaning of "spare"

Tags: vocabulary

there, I got a sentence when I watched the televison "Lost". The sentence is `"Please respect me enough to spare me the pretense that you are actually offended."`

I am confused with "**spare me the pretense**", what's meaning of "spare" here? I looked up dictionary, but I still could not get a proper meaning for this sentence.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*[Spare](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/spare)*

> Verb
>
> 2.0 Refrain from killing, injuring, or *distressing*:
>
> 2.1 [WITH TWO OBJECTS] Refrain from inflicting (something unpleasant) on (someone):

*[Spare me](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/spare)* is also an idiomatic set phrase:

> *spare someone something*
>
> to exempt someone from having to listen to or experience something.
>
> *I'll spare you the details and get to the point.*
>
> *Please, spare me the story and tell me what you want.*

Comment: It's curious how this word got to have two contradicting senses of _give_ and _refrain_.